# Pandas Python - Extract rows based on multiple conditions. data example included

Tags: python, dataframe

I am trying to extract row from dataframe1 to dataframe2 based on condition, but I am struggling, Anyone could help me? It would be so awesome.

dataframe1 :

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1001, 'democrat',0.23],[1001, 'republican',0.7],[1001, 'others',0.07],[1003, 'democrat',0.33],[1003, 'republican',0.44],[1003, 'others',0.23]], columns=['Fips_code', 'Partisan', 'Vote_Pct'])
```

dataframe2 :

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[1001],[1003], [1005]], columns=['Fips_code'])
```

I want to add three columns into dataframe2 as below ('democrat_vote_pct','republican_vote_pct','others_vote_pct') based on fips code condition.

Desired out :

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[1001,0.23,0.7,0.07],[1003,0.33,0.44,0.23], [1005, NA, NA, NA]], columns=['Fips_code','democrat_vote_pct','republican_vote_pct','others_vote_pct'])
```

Please help me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
_df2 = df1.pivot_table(values='Vote_Pct', index='Fips_code', columns='Partisan')
```

And then:

```
result = df2.merge(_df2, on='Fips_code', how='left')
```

Which gives you what you want:

```
   Fips_code  democrat  others  republican
0       1001      0.23    0.07        0.70
1       1003      0.33    0.23        0.44
2       1005       NaN     NaN         NaN
```

If you want the columns to have different names, just give it a `.rename()`

```
new_cols = {'democrat': 'democrat_pct_votes',
            'others': 'others_pct_votes',
            'republican': 'republican_pct_votes'}
df2.rename(new_cols, axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Comment: I got an error, but I could handle with the idea of using pivot table. Thanks!